# TypeError after trying to send pickled data using socket

Tags: python, image, sockets, python-2.7, pickle

I'm trying to send an image from the server to the client so I thought I'd use pickle for serializing the image.

**The code for the server:**

```
import socket
import cPickle as pickle

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1729))

server_socket.listen(1)
(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()

client_request = client_socket.recv(1024)

if client_request == 'IMG':
    img_data =  actions.options[client_request]()
    client_socket.send(pickle.dump(img_data, -1))
else:
    client_socket.send(actions.options[client_request]())

server_socket.close()
```

but when I try to run it (after checking that `img_data` is created correctly), I get the error:

`File "C:/py_prog/my_server.py", line 25, in <module>
    client_socket.send(pickle.dump(img_data, -1))
TypeError: argument must have 'write' attribute`

How can I change the attributes of the pickled data to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get pickled string, you should use [`pickle.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps), not [`pickle.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump) (which accepts a file-like object for the second parameter)

```
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> pickle.dump('not a real image data', -1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument must have 'write' attribute
>>> pickle.dumps('not a real image data', -1)
'\x80\x02U\x15not a real image dataq\x01.'
```

---

```
client_socket.send(pickle.dumps(img_data, -1))
                              ^
```

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, Yes, unless you want load it from file-like object. `pickle.loads` accepts the pickled string.

Comment: I tried it now and got `EOFError` without any explanations about what's wrong.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, It would be nice if you show me the full traceback.

Comment: The traceback was `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/py-prog/client.py", line 21, in <module>
    actions_funcs.show_img(data)
  File "C:/py-prog\actions_funcs.py", line 41, in show_img
    img = pickle.loads(data)
EOFError` . I checked the len of pickled data and its bigger than 1024. Is there any way to predict the size of pickled output?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, The reason for the error is that you didn't provided complete pickled string. IOW, you didn't received the full pickled string.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, I don't know how to predict the size of pickled string. You need some kind of `header` that represent length of payload.

Comment: the image is a screenshot of the server screen. Can I predict the size of pickled data suppose I get its resolution?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, No, I don't know how to do it. You may need to watch pickle implementation if you want.

Comment: thanks. however, I changed the len of socket to 2147483647 (max size of int32)

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, That's not a right way to do it. You'd better modify your protocol as I mentioned in previous comment (especially if you use TCP because sometime you may not receive what you want receive at once)

Comment: I know and I feel really bad doing it must confess. What do you mean by changing protocol ?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, I mean: prepending length field before the real content.

Comment: but I don't know the length of the real content so how can I prepend length field without using this constant?

Comment: @CoarguAliquis, `pickled = pickle.dumps(img_data, -1)`. You can use `len`: `len(pickle)` :)